# Using an Encrypted Realm in a background or notification processes?

Tags: ios, encryption, realm, keychain

Realm has a great [write up](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#encryption) and [sample code](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/Encryption/ViewController.swift) for encrypting your database. This documentation and sample work as intended, until you try to decrypt realm when:

1. A user has a password on their phone
2. The device is locked
3. Your app is trying to do work with Realm when a remote notification comes in

This happens because we can't access the keychain to get (or create) the key to en/decrypt the Realm. The default `kSecAttrAccessible` value is `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`

There are a few options as I see them:

1. Change `kSecAttrAccessible` to `kSecAttrAccessibleAlways`. I don't like this because it's a) too open and b) it was [slated to be deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112678/ksecattraccessiblealways-deprecated-in-ios-9#comment53491023_32600761) in iOS 9
2. Change `kSecAttrAccessible` to `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` or `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`. This is better but still feels too open to me, even though the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/ksecattraccessibleafterfirstunlockthisdeviceonly) state: This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by background applications
3. Create a second, non-encrypted Realm to use as a staging database. Store notification data here, then when the app wakes up from user interaction (the device would be unlocked), move the data from the staging Realm into the encrypted real one. This doesn't feel right either, as we'll have data temporarily not encrypted
4. Combine 2 and 3 and encrypt the staging Realm, and protect it's key with `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly`
5. ??

I'm currently trying to decide if #2, if #3 is worth putting the time into, or if I can come up with a #5

Is there an approach here that I clearly should use or one I've missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an author of [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) library. I strong recommend you to use `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` (The 2nd option). It is the best way to access keychain items from the background.

Comment: Thanks, over kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly? I was leaning towards that but then realized that would get wonky real fast when a User restores their phone (if the DB copied over but it's key didn't)

Comment: Also, AWESOME looking library

Comment: Yes `~ThisDeviceOnly` means the items will never migrate to a new device (= not backed up). I recommend to use `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` rather than `~ThisDeviceOnly` for usability if you don't have special reasons. Most users expect to be restored their passwords from an encrypted backup.